# A regular expression which covers all symbols?

Tags: php, regex

I am fetching a value in `$_GET['id']` from a page to other. The id's are numeric from 1 to 1000. Now when i put different characters from keyboard in the url i get exceptions. I have covered for the a-z and forward slash with the regular expression as:

```
if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z\/]/',$film_id)) {
        echo 'Invalid id for the film';
        die();
}
```

But how to deal with when i put symbols like % $ * ; etc. in the url.
Please help me.

Comment: "symbols like % $ * ; etc.": could you clearly define what you call a symbol?

Comment: Why not just cast `$film_id` as an integer and check that it is between 1 and 1000?

Comment: i did that already but surely for that i had to do `if($film_id == 0)` which made me feel a bit brittle.

Comment: What about `if($film_id < 1 || $film_id > 1000) { die('invalid')` and cast that as an int. You don't want to validate numeric ranges with a regex.

Comment: when i casted it as int everything which was a character represented 0 as int and i got success but wanted to this with a regular expression which sensed more semantic to me. Thanks anyway @chris85

Comment: so if your ids are numeric..... is there any reason why you don't simply validate with the built-in function **[is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)**?

Comment: `$_GET['id']` is a string so that would not work i suppose.

Comment: @JotWaraich have you even *looked* at the manual link i have provided? did you read the *first line*, which states "finds whether a variable is a number or a **numeric string**"?

Comment: sorry didnt do it @Franz Gleichmann. The answer below was appropriate so i was satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said the ids are numeric, so:

```
if(preg_match('/\D/',$film_id)) {
        echo 'Invalid id for the film';
        die();
}
```

will do the job

Comment: Sorry but your first answer was not appropriate you edited the answer and the new answer worked

Comment: @JotWaraich: If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, it'll be useful for future readers.

Comment: I dont have much reputation Toto.....after this people keep on marking down the questions that i ask...it is very difficult to make reputation here